# items not adding to a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

i want to add items in a sql database to a dictionary but the values enter as null in the object reference heres the code im using atm

```
public static Dictionary<string, prizedbinfo> dbprizes = new Dictionary<string, prizedbinfo>();

    private void LoadData(string dataloc)
    {
            if (!File.Exists(dataloc))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(dataloc + " not found.");
                return;
            }
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dataloc);
            connection.Open();

            var datacommand = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT prizeID, createdOn, expiresOn, modifiedOn, status, redeemedOn, giftedOn, claimedOn FROM mySnackData", connection);
            List<string[]> datas = ExecuteStringCommand(datacommand, 9);

            foreach (string[] row in datas)
            {
                if (!Program.dbprizes.ContainsKey(row[0]))
                {
                    Program.dbprizes.Add(row[0], new prizedbinfo(row));
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
    }
```

and the prizedbinfo object is

```
class prizedbinfo
{
    public prizedbinfo(string[] dbdata)
    {
        string prizeID = dbdata[0];
        string createdOn = dbdata[1];
        string expiresOn = dbdata[2];
        string modifiedOn = dbdata[3];
        string status = dbdata[4];
        string redeemedOn = dbdata[5];
        string giftedOn = dbdata[6];
        string claimedOn = dbdata[7];
        string name = dbdata[8];
    }
    public string prizeID { get; set; }
    public string createdOn { get; set; }
    public string expiresOn { get; set; }
    public string modifiedOn { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string redeemedOn { get; set; }
    public string giftedOn { get; set; }
    public string claimedOn { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

}
```

i have tested it with breakpoints and all the data is correctly added to datas and row but not to the prizedbinfo object for some reason

Comment: Did you check your compiler warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `string` keyword from all your variables in the `prizedbinfo` constructor. You're creating local variables that immediately go out of scope, so you're losing your values.

```
public prizedbinfo(string[] dbdata)
{
    prizeID = dbdata[0];
    createdOn = dbdata[1];
    expiresOn = dbdata[2];
    modifiedOn = dbdata[3];
    status = dbdata[4];
    redeemedOn = dbdata[5];
    giftedOn = dbdata[6];
    claimedOn = dbdata[7];
    name = dbdata[8];
}
```

Comment: thanks that fixed it i have been working on this all day cant beleive it was so simple i will accept when it lets me